# Missing libraries when trying to run a julia program

Tags: shared-library, julia-lang

So I am new to Linux and I was trying to run a Julia program using

```
 julia transport.jl
```

However when enter that in terminal I get the following

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: error compiling init: could not load library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
while loading /home/david/.julia/v0.4/Tk/src/tkwidget.jl, in expression starting on line 455
while loading /home/david/.julia/v0.4/Tk/src/Tk.jl, in expression starting on line 37
while loading /home/david/.julia/v0.4/Winston/src/tk.jl, in expression starting on line 1
while loading /home/david/.julia/v0.4/Winston/src/Winston.jl, in expression starting on line 2854
while loading /home/david/Documents/School/PDE1/examples/transport.jl, in expression starting on line 2
```

Any help would help, especially any literature that will introduce me to the Linux environment.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: How did you install Julia?

Comment: I downloaded the tar, extracted it into its own folder, ran sudo apt-get install julia, then finally created a symbolic link to it.

Comment: Why did you do that? Running `sudo apt install julia` would handle the installation fully and you wouldn't need to do anything else. What symlink did you create? That is probably the cause of the problem. Please [edit] your question and add more information...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing libglib2.0

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0
```

Comment: I get the following
     `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
         libglib2.0-dev : Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)`

Comment: Try to resolve that with `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: That did nothing

Comment: Can you try to install python? `sudo apt-get install python`

Comment: Nothing happens again. It says I have Python 2.7.13-1

Comment: Tried that and it says I already have Python. Also i did `sudo apt autoremove` then `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0` and it worked. However it seems like I am still getting the same error when trying to compile Julia program